# Reference request for studying Ring of continious functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

I have studied basic Ring theory from Basic Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote up to UFD.I wish to study more on the Ring of continious functions on my own.I know a little bit Topology and the basics of analysis.Can someone suggest me a user friendly book which will help me to study the Ring of continious functions in moe detail.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The classic reference and an excellent book (IMHO) is Leonard Gillman and Meyer Jerison, *Rings of continuous functions*. Lots of exercises and a clear exposition. I consider it mostly a topology book (though there is some ring theory in it).

Comment: Thank You Sir!!I'll look into it